# store data in text file or xml

Tags: xml, storage

If I want to store some simple data of personal expense,including category(string),date(string) and amount (double) in order to generate some summary report, which is a better way?
I am thinking about using stream and txt file and output these data manually; I have never used xml before. what is the advantage of xml?

If the data is going to be used only by my program, and it is not complicatedly structured, does it mean text file is a better choice?

Comment: Pen/Paper or using your memory?

Comment: how to deal with xml in c++?

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of xml is that it's a standardized format, other programs will be able to read it if they need to. If you are storing things in a txt file, the conventions are up to you (spacing, separators, representation of numbers, ... ) and likely incompatible with other code.

I'd personally consider a light embedded database such as `sqlite` for this job.

(`double` is not a suitable format for storing prices/salaries. Consider a fixed-point representation, or failing that, as a workaround, store the number of cents as a `long`.)

Answer (score 0):

Main advantage of existing XML APIs: handle escaping for you (you can write any text inside) and good unicode support.

Main disadvantage: performance. If you want to handle large sets of data fast, do something else.